# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in XController#destroy Rails 3.2. Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, destroy, http-delete

I am pretty new to web development but suddenly this error appears every time I want to delete something.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in XController#destroy 
Couldn't find X with id=577
```

It doesn't matter if it is X, Y or Z. In the database the content is deleted. I have to hit the `back button` in the `browser` to see that the X, Y or Z is deleted.

I do not `redirect_to` a deleted object. Even if I `redirect_to` an `index page` the error appears.

Does this have to do something with the `cache`? Should I clear it? Could I use `expire` for it?

EDIT

```
 def destroy
 @x= X.find(params[:id])
 @x.destroy

 respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to xs_url }
   format.json { head :no_content }
 end
end
```

Here is one part of the views

```
 <td><% if can? :destroy, x %><%= link_to image_tag("bin.png", { :title => t(:destroy) }), x, method: :delete, data: { confirm: t(:are_you_sure) } %><% end %></td>
```

Thank you in advance =)

Comment: paste your controller code

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
 def destroy
   @x = X.where(id: params[:id]).first
   @x.destroy unless @x.blank?

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html { redirect_to xs_url }
   format.json { head :no_content }
  end
 end
```

Comment: This works just for X. If I want to delete Y it does not work. The `controller` for Y is the following: `def destroy
  @x = X.find(params[:x_id])
  @y = @x.ys.find(params[:id])
  @y.destroy
  redirect_to x_path(@x)
  end`  If I try your code with Y the same error (just for Y) appears. I really don't understand. It used to work earlier...

Comment: try `def destroy @y= Y.where(id: params[:id]).first  @y.destroy unless @y.blank?  end`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. There is now a new error `Couldn't find Y with id=10222 [WHERE ys.x_id = 169]`

Comment: @DaMaNaMu `id =10222` is Y id or X id?

Comment: In this case it is Y = 10222. I am wondering why it is actually deleted but also rises this error.